# How To Create Line Chart With afreechart api?

Tags: android

I am new with afree chart api. I created pie and column chart with this but I don't know how to create line chart with this api?

```
AFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart
                (
                    "Line Chart Demo",  // title
                    "Date",             // x-axis label
                    "Price Per Unit",   // y-axis label
                    dataset,            // data (how to create this dataset)
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                    true,               // create legend?
                    true,               // generate tooltips?
                    false               // generate URLs?
                );
```

Comment: Check the demo code from the developers of afreechart [link](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/source/browse/trunk/afreechart_sample/?r=41)

Comment: @Fabian : there is no demo for Line chart bro. thats why i posted question here..